# Cython compiled module does not allow access to the function defined 'module' not callable

Tags: python, cython

ORIGINAL ERROR FOUND -> `from CyBlack.CyBlack import CyBlack` then pass `*numpy_value` as inputs.  A new issue has arisen so creating a new post for that.
[Cython program with numpy arrays does not allow vectorized inputs (only accepts length 1 arrays), how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167147/cython-program-with-numpy-arrays-does-not-allow-vectorized-inputs-only-calcs-1)

I am new to Cython and tried converting the Black (Black Scholes without a stock dividend) over from Python to Cython.  After getting it to compile, it doesn't let me actually use the function.  I'm sure someone with more experience can look at this easily and figure out why.  The error I get after compiling and importing the function `from CyBlack import CyBlack` and calling `CyBlack(BlackPnL, Black_S, Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)` is `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`: So here's the code:

```
from numpy cimport ndarray
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double)
    double sqrt(double)
    double pow(double)
    double log(double)
    double erf(double)

cdef double std_norm_cdf(double x):
    return 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2.0)))

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef CyBlack(ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] BlackPnL, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_S, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_Texpiry, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_strike, ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_volatility, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_IR, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_callput):

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = BlackPnL.shape[0]
    cdef double d1, d2


    for i in range(N):
        d1 = ((log(Black_S[i] / Black_strike[i]) + Black_Texpiry[i] * Black_volatility[i] **2 / 2)) / (Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i]))
        d2 = d1 - Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i])
        BlackPnL[i] = exp(-Black_IR[i] * Black_Texpiry[i]) * (Black_callput[i] * Black_S[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d1) - Black_callput[i] * Black_strike[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d2)) 

    return BlackPnL
```

Thanks for any help here!  I can post python fake data if you need something to test off of - although just calling it with any data will expose the error...  Something points me to the variables not being exposed to Python from the C code.

Adding my `setup.py` here so others can build this typing: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` built with VS2015 for Python 3.5 64bit Windows.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("CyBlack.pyx"), include_dirs =["C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//include", "C://Program Files (x86)//Windows Kits//10//Include//10.0.1.0240.0//ucrt", "C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//lib//amd64", "C://Anaconda3//Lib//site-packages//numpy//core//include", "C://Program Files (x86)//Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0//VC//lib//amd64"])
```

Comment: It sounds like this `CyBlack` module might actually be embedded in a `CyBlack` package. Your `CyBlack` function is cdef'ed instead of cpdef'ed, so it's not going to be accessible through any Python import.

Comment: I cpdef'd it and still the same issue...

Comment: Could you post the result of  `from CyBlack import CyBlack; print(CyBlack.__file__)`? This should output the path to the module causing the error.

Comment: What's your directory structure (i.e. is your module in a directory called `cyBlack`)?

Comment: Yes in a directory called CyBlack.  It imports without error it just doesn't let you send arguments to the function

Comment: @SergeiLebedev the output of that command is: C:\Users\slezm0\Documents\Python Scripts\CyBlack\CyBlack.cp35-win_amd64.pyd which is what I expected.  The issue seems to be more like exposing the function variables to Python from the Cython code I believe... waiting for bounty time I'll post 50pts and award to anyone that figures out the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get (something like it) working in the following way:

```
C:/dev/tmp/CyBlack/
                   __init__.py
                   setup.py
                   CyBlack.pyx
```

Where `CyBlack.pyx` is just like yours, except with `CyBlack` function being `cpdef`'d. `setup.py` contains:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import numpy
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extra_compile_args = ['/EHsc', '/openmp', '/favor:INTEL64']

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize("CyBlack.pyx"),
    include_dirs=['.', numpy.get_include()],
    extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args
)
```

Running then:

```
C:\dev\tmp\CyBlack> python .\setup.py build_ext --compiler=msvc --inplace
```

Will produce `C:/dev/tmp/CyBlack/CyBlack.pyd`, and I then managed to run the code from Python:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> path.insert(0, "C:/dev/tmp")
>>> from CyBlack.CyBlack import CyBlack
>>> CyBlack(*[np.array([1.0]) for _ in xrange(7)]) # I'm too lazy to put proper values here...
array([ 0.14087021])
```

This was done with **Python 2.7**, and overall setup might be slightly different, but hopefully, that might help you getting a minimum working example and trace back how to make yours run correctly.

Comment: thank you for posting the running example.  I actually found the buried module at the same time you did coincidentally.  The only issue now is that the function is not allowing numpy vectors to be processed (kind of defeats the purpose of having an internal loop) as I thought that was the point of declaring numpy array types in the cython block.

Comment: I had issues passing in `nd` vectors as well, which I suspect come from the use of the C `log` and `sqrt` rather than the (vectorised) numpy ones; not sure if this is what is causing it

Comment: I added the [i] indexing to the code above which should allow 1 value at a time to be passed to `log` and `sqrt`, but no help.  Thinking I've changed this into another question and should just accept your answer and repost part 2...

Answer (score -2):

Instead of

```
from CyBlack import CyBlack
```

Why don't you just do

```
import CyBlack
```

?

Comment: That's actually what I tried first...  doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing there's probably a submodule/function called CyBlack inside the CyBlack module. Therefore, if you just did `import CyBlack` then you would probably need to use `CyBlack.CyBlack()` whenever you wanted to use it in the code, if it is in fact a function.