# Cython program with numpy arrays does not allow vectorized inputs (only accepts length 1 arrays), how to fix?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

FIXED: see updated code below.

This is my first Cython attempt and have a working build but it doesn't allow numpy array (vectors) as inputs, which is my real purpose here.  It is the Black model (Black Scholes for European option pricing without a dividend).  It will only accept length 1 arrays as inputs (if I try to calculate with length 2 arrays it errors: `TypeError: CyBlack() takes exactly 7 positional arguments (14 given)`, if I pass length 10 arrays, `(70 given)`, etc.).  I'm not sure why as I have defined numpy arrays within the Cython code.  For reference you can compile it with the below code then use it as such:  `from CyBlack.CyBlack import CyBlack` then calling `CyBlack(BlackPnL, Black_S, Black_Texpiry, Black_strike, Black_volatility, Black_IR, Black_callput)` So here's the code (save as `CyBlack.pyx` file to compile):

```
from numpy cimport ndarray
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

cdef extern from "math.h":
    double exp(double)
    double sqrt(double)
    double log(double)
    double erf(double)

cdef double std_norm_cdf(double x):
    return 0.5*(1+erf(x/sqrt(2.0)))

@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef CyBlack(ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] BlackPnL, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_S, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_Texpiry, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_strike, ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_volatility, ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] Black_IR, ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] Black_callput):

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef Py_ssize_t N = BlackPnL.shape[0]
    cdef double d1, d2


    for i in range(N):
        d1 = ((log(Black_S[i] / Black_strike[i]) + Black_Texpiry[i] * Black_volatility[i] **2 / 2)) / (Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i]))
        d2 = d1 - Black_volatility[i] * sqrt(Black_Texpiry[i])
        BlackPnL[i] = exp(-Black_IR[i] * Black_Texpiry[i]) * (Black_callput[i] * Black_S[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d1) - Black_callput[i] * Black_strike[i] * std_norm_cdf(Black_callput[i] * d2)) 

    return BlackPnL
```

Here is the `setup.py` so others can build this typing: `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` built with VS2015 for Python 3.5 64bit Windows.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

extra_compile_args = ['/EHsc', '/openmp', '/favor:INTEL64']

setup(
ext_modules=cythonize("CyBlack.pyx"),
include_dirs=['.', numpy.get_include()],
extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args)
```

The above compiles and works after using the fix on the variable type (Black_callput was actually an `int64`) and you have to pass the numpy arrays as they are (no star) and it works correctly.

Comment: *"It will only compute 1 value at a time"* - what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: "You have to pass the numpy arrays to the function with a star" - what? Why are you doing that? That is either your entire problem or a very large part of your problem. Show us what arguments you're passing, and how.

Comment: *"You have to pass the numpy arrays to the function with a star, *Black_PnL as an example"* - uh, no you don't! Try passing them in as separate arguments.

Comment: `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t' but got 'long long'` results if you just pass values in without the star.

Comment: OK, now that `ValueError` means you are passing it an int64 array rather than float64 as specified in your input type declarations

Comment: Thanks @ali_m, you're right about that one.  1 of the fields Black_callput is an INT64 type.  It works!!!!

Comment: Post your solution here so I can vote for it and get you some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were two issues here:

1. `TypeError: CyBlack() takes exactly 7 positional arguments (14 given)`

   This was caused by the fact that you were unpacking your input arrays using the `*` ("splat") operator. You needed to pass them in as 7 separate arguments instead.
2. `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float64_t' but got 'long long'`:

   This error was telling you that one of the input arrays had a C type of `long long` (which is a 64 bit integer), rather than `float64_t`as specified in your input type declarations. You needed to cast all of your input arrays to `np.float64`.